# Ordered map for C using AVL tree

Tags: c, tree, hash-map

I was in the mood for some data structures and I decided to code up an ordered map using AVL tree. I will post only `map.h` and `map.c`. The demonstration driver may be found [here](https://github.com/coderodde/coderodde.c.utils/blob/82a7ef078b78a8d93ce766b573211b4e7f6e1592/main.c).

See what I have:

**map.h**:

```
#ifndef MAP_H
#define MAP_H

#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    typedef struct map_entry_t {
        void*               p_key;
        void*               p_value;
        struct map_entry_t* p_left;
        struct map_entry_t* p_right;
        struct map_entry_t* p_parent;
        int                 height;
    } map_entry_t;

    typedef struct map_t {
        map_entry_t* p_root;
        int          (*p_comparator)(void*, void*);
        size_t       size;
        size_t       mod_count;
    } map_t;

    typedef struct map_iterator_t {
        map_t*       p_map;
        map_entry_t* p_next;
        void**       p_ret_array;
        size_t       iterated_count;
        size_t       expected_mod_count;
    } map_iterator_t;

    /***************************************************************************
    * Allocates a new, empty map with given comparator function.               *
    ***************************************************************************/ 
    map_t* map_t_alloc        (int (*p_comparator)(void*, void*));

    /***************************************************************************
    * If p_map contains the key p_key, associates it with value p_value and    *
    * returns the old value of that key.                                       *
    ***************************************************************************/ 
    void*  map_t_put          (map_t* p_map, void* p_key, void* p_value);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Returns a positive value if p_key is mapped to some value in this map.   *
    ***************************************************************************/
    int    map_t_contains_key (map_t* p_map, void* p_key);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Returns the value associated with the p_key, or NULL if p_key is not     *
    * mapped in the map.                                                       *
    ***************************************************************************/
    void*  map_t_get          (map_t* p_map, void* p_key);

    /***************************************************************************
    * If p_key is mapped in the map, removes the mapping and returns the value *
    * of that mapping. If the map did not contain the mapping, return NULL.    *
    ***************************************************************************/ 
    void*  map_t_remove       (map_t* p_map, void* p_key);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Removes all the contents of the map.                                     * 
    ***************************************************************************/ 
    void   map_t_clear        (map_t* p_map);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Returns the size of the map, or namely, the amount of key/value mappings *
    * in the map.                                                              *
    ***************************************************************************/ 
    int    map_t_size         (map_t* p_map);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Checks that the map maintains the AVL-tree invariant.                    *
    ***************************************************************************/  
    int    map_t_is_healthy   (map_t* p_map);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Deallocates the entire map. Only the map and its nodes are deallocated.  *
    * The user is responsible to deallocate the actual data stored in the map. *
    ***************************************************************************/ 
    void   map_t_free         (map_t* p_map);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Returns the iterator over the map. The keys are iterated in order.       *
    ***************************************************************************/  
    map_iterator_t* map_iterator_t_alloc        (map_t* p_map);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Returns the number of keys not yet iterated over.                        *
    ***************************************************************************/ 
    int             map_iterator_t_has_next     (map_iterator_t* p_iterator);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Returns the next key in the iteration order.                             *
    ***************************************************************************/  
    void**          map_iterator_t_next         (map_iterator_t* p_iterator);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Returns a positive integer if the map was modified during the iteration. *
    ***************************************************************************/  
    int             map_iterator_t_is_disturbed (map_iterator_t* p_iterator);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Deallocates the map iterator.                                            *
    ***************************************************************************/  
    void            map_iterator_t_free         (map_iterator_t* p_iterator);

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  /* MAP_H */
```

**map.c**:

```
#include "map.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE (~FALSE)

/*******************************************************************************
* Creates a new map entry and initializes its fields.                          *
*******************************************************************************/  
static map_entry_t* map_entry_t_alloc(void* p_key, void* p_value) 
{
    map_entry_t* p_ret = malloc(sizeof(*p_ret));

    if (!p_ret) return NULL;

    p_ret->p_key    = p_key;
    p_ret->p_value  = p_value;
    p_ret->p_left   = NULL;
    p_ret->p_right  = NULL;
    p_ret->p_parent = NULL;
    p_ret->height   = 0;

    return p_ret;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns the height of an entry. The height of a non-existent entry is        *
* assumed to be -1.                                                            *
*******************************************************************************/
static int height(map_entry_t* p_node) 
{
    return p_node ? p_node->height : -1;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns the maximum of the two input integers.                               *
*******************************************************************************/
static int max(int a, int b) 
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Performs a left rotation and returns the new root of a (sub)tree.            *
*******************************************************************************/
static map_entry_t* left_rotate(map_entry_t* p_node_1)
{
    map_entry_t* p_node_2 = p_node_1->p_right;
    p_node_2->p_parent   = p_node_1->p_parent;
    p_node_1->p_parent   = p_node_2;
    p_node_1->p_right    = p_node_2->p_left;
    p_node_2->p_left     = p_node_1;

    if (p_node_1->p_right) p_node_1->p_right->p_parent = p_node_1;

    p_node_1->height = max(height(p_node_1->p_left), 
                           height(p_node_1->p_right)) + 1;
    p_node_2->height = max(height(p_node_2->p_left),
                           height(p_node_2->p_right)) + 1;
    return p_node_2;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Performs a right rotation and returns the new root of a (sub)tree.           *
*******************************************************************************/
static map_entry_t* right_rotate(map_entry_t* p_node_1)
{
    map_entry_t* p_node_2 = p_node_1->p_left;
    p_node_2->p_parent   = p_node_1->p_parent;
    p_node_1->p_parent   = p_node_2;
    p_node_1->p_left     = p_node_2->p_right;
    p_node_2->p_right    = p_node_1;

    if (p_node_1->p_left) p_node_1->p_left->p_parent = p_node_1;

    p_node_1->height = max(height(p_node_1->p_left),
                           height(p_node_1->p_right)) + 1;
    p_node_2->height = max(height(p_node_2->p_left),
                           height(p_node_2->p_right)) + 1;
    return p_node_2;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Performs a right rotation following by a left rotation and returns the root  *
* of the new (sub)tree.                                                        * 
*******************************************************************************/
static map_entry_t* right_left_rotate(map_entry_t* p_node_1) 
{
    map_entry_t* p_node_2 = p_node_1->p_right;
    p_node_1->p_right = right_rotate(p_node_2);
    return left_rotate(p_node_1);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Performs a left rotation following by a right rotation and returns the root  *
* of the new (sub)tree.                                                        * 
*******************************************************************************/
static map_entry_t* left_right_rotate(map_entry_t* p_node_1)
{
    map_entry_t* p_node_2 = p_node_1->p_left;
    p_node_1->p_left = left_rotate(p_node_2);
    return right_rotate(p_node_1);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Fixes the tree in order to balance it. Basically, we start from 'p_entry'    *
* go up the chain towards parents. If a parent is disbalanced, a set of        *
* rotations are applied. If 'insertion_mode' is on, it means that previous     *  
* modification was insertion of an entry. In such a case we need to perform    *
* only one rotation. If 'insertion_mode' is off, the last operation was        *
* removal and we need to go up until the root node.                            *
*******************************************************************************/  
static void fix_after_modification(map_t* p_map, 
                                   map_entry_t* p_entry,
                                   int insertion_mode)
{
    map_entry_t* p_parent = p_entry->p_parent;
    map_entry_t* p_grand_parent;
    map_entry_t* p_sub_tree;

    while (p_parent) 
    {
        if (height(p_parent->p_left) == height(p_parent->p_right) + 2)
        {
            p_grand_parent = p_parent->p_parent;

            if (height(p_parent->p_left->p_left) > 
                height(p_parent->p_left->p_right)) 
                p_sub_tree = right_rotate(p_parent);
            else 
                p_sub_tree = left_right_rotate(p_parent);

            if (!p_grand_parent) 
                p_map->p_root = p_sub_tree;
            else if (p_grand_parent->p_left == p_parent) 
                p_grand_parent->p_left = p_sub_tree;
            else
                p_grand_parent->p_right = p_sub_tree;

            if (p_grand_parent)
                p_grand_parent->height = 
                        max(height(p_grand_parent->p_left),
                                   height(p_grand_parent->p_right)) + 1;

            /* Fixing after insertion requires only one rotation. */
            if (insertion_mode) return;
        }

        if (height(p_parent->p_right) == height(p_parent->p_left) + 2) 
        {
            p_grand_parent = p_parent->p_parent;

            if (height(p_parent->p_right->p_right) > 
                height(p_parent->p_right->p_left)) 
                p_sub_tree = left_rotate(p_parent);
            else
                p_sub_tree = right_left_rotate(p_parent);

            if (!p_grand_parent)
                p_map->p_root = p_sub_tree;
            else if (p_grand_parent->p_left == p_parent)
                p_grand_parent->p_left = p_sub_tree;
            else
                p_grand_parent->p_right = p_sub_tree;

            if (p_grand_parent)
                p_grand_parent->height = 
                        max(height(p_grand_parent->p_left),
                            height(p_grand_parent->p_right)) + 1;

            /* Fixing after insertion requires only one rotation. */
            if (insertion_mode) return;
        }

        p_parent->height = max(height(p_parent->p_left),
                               height(p_parent->p_right)) + 1;
        p_parent = p_parent->p_parent;
    }
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Performs the actual insertion of an entry.                                   *
*******************************************************************************/
static int insert(map_t* p_map, void* p_key, void* p_value) 
{
    map_entry_t* p_new_entry = map_entry_t_alloc(p_key, p_value);
    map_entry_t* p_x;
    map_entry_t* p_parent;

    if (!p_new_entry) return (EXIT_FAILURE);

    if (!p_map->p_root)
    {
        p_map->p_root = p_new_entry;
        p_map->size++;
        p_map->mod_count++;
        return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    p_x = p_map->p_root;
    p_parent = NULL;

    while (p_x) 
    {
        p_parent = p_x;

        if (p_map->p_comparator(p_new_entry->p_key, p_x->p_key) < 0)
            p_x = p_x->p_left;
        else
            p_x = p_x->p_right;
    }

    p_new_entry->p_parent = p_parent;

    if (p_map->p_comparator(p_new_entry->p_key, p_parent->p_key) < 0) 
        p_parent->p_left = p_new_entry;
    else
        p_parent->p_right = p_new_entry;

    /** TRUE means we choose the insertion mode for fixing the tree. */
    fix_after_modification(p_map, p_new_entry, TRUE);
    p_map->size++;
    p_map->mod_count++;
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns the minimum entry of a subtree rooted at 'p_entry'.                  *
*******************************************************************************/  
static map_entry_t* min_entry(map_entry_t* p_entry)
{
    while (p_entry->p_left) p_entry = p_entry->p_left;
    return p_entry;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns the successor entry as specified by the order implied by the         *
* comparator.                                                                  *
*******************************************************************************/
static map_entry_t* get_successor_entry(map_entry_t* p_entry)
{
    map_entry_t* p_parent;

    if (p_entry->p_right) return min_entry(p_entry->p_right);

    p_parent = p_entry->p_parent;

    while (p_parent && p_parent->p_right == p_entry)
    {
        p_entry = p_parent;
        p_parent = p_parent->p_parent;
    }

    return p_parent;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* This routine is responsible for removing entries from the tree.              *
*******************************************************************************/  
static map_entry_t* delete_entry(map_t* p_map, map_entry_t* p_entry)
{
    map_entry_t* p_parent;
    map_entry_t* p_child;
    map_entry_t* p_successor;

    void* p_tmp_key;
    void* p_tmp_value;

    if (!p_entry->p_left && !p_entry->p_right)
    {
        /** The node to delete has no children. */
        p_parent = p_entry->p_parent;

        if (!p_parent) 
        {
            p_map->p_root = NULL;
            p_map->size--;
            p_map->mod_count++;
            return p_entry;
        }

        if (p_entry == p_parent->p_left) 
            p_parent->p_left = NULL;
        else
            p_parent->p_right = NULL;

        p_map->size--;
        p_map->mod_count++;
        return p_entry;
    }

    if (!p_entry->p_left || !p_entry->p_right)
    {
        /** The node has exactly one child. */
        if (p_entry->p_left)
            p_child = p_entry->p_left;
        else
            p_child = p_entry->p_right;

        p_parent = p_entry->p_parent;
        p_child->p_parent = p_parent;

        if (!p_parent) 
        {
            p_map->p_root = p_child;
            p_map->size--;
            p_map->mod_count++;
            return p_entry;
        }

        if (p_entry == p_parent->p_left)
            p_parent->p_left = p_child;
        else 
            p_parent->p_right = p_child;

        p_map->size--;
        p_map->mod_count++;
        return p_entry;
    }

    /** The node to remove has both children. */
    p_tmp_key        = p_entry->p_key;
    p_tmp_value      = p_entry->p_value;
    p_successor      = min_entry(p_entry->p_right);
    p_entry->p_key   = p_successor->p_key;
    p_entry->p_value = p_successor->p_value;
    p_child          = p_successor->p_right;
    p_parent         = p_successor->p_parent;

    if (p_parent->p_left == p_successor)
        p_parent->p_left = p_child;
    else
        p_parent->p_right = p_child;

    if (p_child)
        p_child->p_parent = p_parent;

    p_map->size--;
    p_map->mod_count++;
    p_successor->p_key   = p_tmp_key;
    p_successor->p_value = p_tmp_value;
    return p_successor;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Searches for an entry with key 'key'. Returns NULL if there is no such.      *
*******************************************************************************/  
static map_entry_t* find_entry(map_t* p_map, void* key)
{
    map_entry_t* p_entry = p_map->p_root;

    while (p_entry && p_entry->p_key != key)
    {
        if (p_map->p_comparator(key, p_entry->p_key) < 0)
            p_entry = p_entry->p_left;
        else 
            p_entry = p_entry->p_right;
    }

    return p_entry;
}

map_t* map_t_alloc(int (*p_comparator)(void*, void*)) 
{
    map_t* p_ret;

    if (!p_comparator) return NULL;

    p_ret = malloc(sizeof(*p_ret));

    if (!p_ret) return NULL;

    p_ret->p_root = NULL;
    p_ret->p_comparator = p_comparator;
    p_ret->size = 0;
    p_ret->mod_count = 0;

    return p_ret;
}

void* map_t_put(map_t* p_map, void* p_key, void* p_value)
{
    map_entry_t* p_target;
    void* p_old_value;

    if (!p_map)               return NULL;
    if (!p_map->p_comparator) return NULL;

    p_target = find_entry(p_map, p_key);

    if (p_target)
    {
        p_old_value = p_target->p_value;
        p_target->p_value = p_value;
        return p_old_value; 
    } 

    insert(p_map, p_key, p_value);
    return NULL;
}

int map_t_contains_key (map_t* p_map, void* p_key)
{
    if (!p_map)               return 0;
    if (!p_map->p_comparator) return 0;

    return find_entry(p_map, p_key) ? 1 : 0;
}

void* map_t_get(map_t* p_map, void* p_key)
{
    map_entry_t* p_entry;

    if (!p_map)               return NULL;
    if (!p_map->p_comparator) return NULL;

    p_entry = find_entry(p_map, p_key);
    return p_entry ? p_entry->p_value : NULL;
}

void* map_t_remove(map_t* p_map, void* p_key)
{
    void* ret;
    map_entry_t* p_entry;

    if (!p_map)               return NULL;
    if (!p_map->p_comparator) return NULL;

    p_entry = find_entry(p_map, p_key);

    if (!p_entry) return NULL;

    ret = p_entry->p_value;
    p_entry = delete_entry(p_map, p_entry);
    fix_after_modification(p_map, p_entry, FALSE);
    free(p_entry);
    return ret;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* This routine implements the actual checking of tree balance.                 *
*******************************************************************************/  
static int check_balance_factors_impl(map_entry_t* p_entry)
{
    if (!p_entry) return 1;
    if (abs(height(p_entry->p_left) - height(p_entry->p_right)) > 1) return 0;
    if (!check_balance_factors_impl(p_entry->p_left))  return 0;
    if (!check_balance_factors_impl(p_entry->p_right)) return 0;
    return 1;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Checks that every node in the map is balanced.                               *
*******************************************************************************/  
static int check_balance_factors(map_t* p_map) 
{
    return check_balance_factors_impl(p_map->p_root);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* This routine implements the actual height verification algorithm. It uses a  *
* sentinel value of -2 for denoting the fact that a current subtree contains   *
* at least one unbalanced node.                                                *  
*******************************************************************************/  
static int check_heights_impl(map_entry_t* p_entry)
{
    int height_left;
    int height_right;
    int height_both;

    /**********************************************************
    * The base case: the height of a non-existent leaf is -1. *
    **********************************************************/ 
    if (!p_entry) return -1;

    height_left = check_heights_impl(p_entry->p_left) + 1;

    if (height_left == -2) return -2;

    height_right = check_heights_impl(p_entry->p_right) + 1;

    if (height_right == -2)  return -2;

    if ((height_both = max(height_left, 
                           height_right)) != p_entry->height) return -2;

    return height_both;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* This routine checks that the height field of each map entry (node) is        *
* correct.                                                                     *
*******************************************************************************/  
static int check_heights(map_t* p_map)
{
    return check_heights_impl(p_map->p_root) != -2;
}

int map_t_is_healthy(map_t* p_map) 
{
    if (!p_map) return 0;

    if (!check_heights(p_map)) return 0;

    return check_balance_factors(p_map);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Implements the actual deallocation of the tree entries by traversing the     *
* tree in post-order.                                                          * 
*******************************************************************************/  
static void map_free_impl(map_entry_t* p_entry)
{
    if (!p_entry) return;

    map_free_impl(p_entry->p_left);
    map_free_impl(p_entry->p_right);
    free(p_entry);
}

void map_t_free(map_t* p_map) 
{
    if (!p_map)         return;
    if (!p_map->p_root) return;

    map_free_impl(p_map->p_root);
    free(p_map);
}

void map_t_clear(map_t* p_map) 
{
    if (!p_map)         return;
    if (!p_map->p_root) return;

    map_free_impl(p_map->p_root);
    p_map->mod_count += p_map->size;
    p_map->p_root = NULL;
    p_map->size = 0;
}

int map_t_size(map_t* p_map) 
{
    return p_map ? p_map->size : -1;
}

map_iterator_t* map_iterator_t_alloc(map_t* p_map)
{
    if (!p_map) return NULL;
    map_iterator_t* p_iterator = malloc(sizeof(*p_iterator));
    p_iterator->expected_mod_count = p_map->mod_count;
    p_iterator->iterated_count = 0;
    p_iterator->p_map = p_map;
    p_iterator->p_next = p_map->p_root ? min_entry(p_map->p_root) : NULL;
    p_iterator->p_ret_array = calloc(2, sizeof(void*));
    return p_iterator;
}

int map_iterator_t_has_next(map_iterator_t* p_iterator) 
{
    if (!p_iterator)        return FALSE;
    if (!p_iterator->p_map) return FALSE;

    /** If the map was modified, stop iteration. */
    if (map_iterator_t_is_disturbed(p_iterator)) return FALSE;

    return p_iterator->iterated_count < p_iterator->p_map->size;
}

void** map_iterator_t_next(map_iterator_t* p_iterator)
{
    if (!p_iterator)        return NULL;
    if (!p_iterator->p_map) return NULL;
    if (map_iterator_t_is_disturbed(p_iterator)) return NULL;

    p_iterator->p_ret_array[0] = p_iterator->p_next->p_key;
    p_iterator->p_ret_array[1] = p_iterator->p_next->p_value;
    p_iterator->iterated_count++;
    p_iterator->p_next = get_successor_entry(p_iterator->p_next);
    return p_iterator->p_ret_array;
}

int map_iterator_t_is_disturbed(map_iterator_t* p_iterator) 
{
    if (!p_iterator)        return FALSE;
    if (!p_iterator->p_map) return FALSE;

    return p_iterator->expected_mod_count != p_iterator->p_map->mod_count;
}

void map_iterator_t_free(map_iterator_t* p_iterator) 
{
    free(p_iterator->p_ret_array);
    p_iterator->p_map = NULL;
    p_iterator->p_next = NULL;
    p_iterator->p_ret_array = NULL;
    free(p_iterator);
}
```

Now, a couple of questions:

1. Do identifiers communicate their purpose clearly?
2. Is there a room for optimization?
3. Am I doing idiomatic C here?
4. Any idea how I should go about testing the data structure?
5. How can I improve the way I comment functions?
6. The tree is responsible for memory-managing its own structures. So am I leaking memory anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Hide implentation

In your header, I would remove all the structure definitions and leave only the typedefs.  External users of your map shouldn't need to see into your structures.  You can keep the structure definitions private by defining them only in your .c file.

## const

I think all of the keys and values should be marked `const`, since you never modify them.  Also, various functions could have `const` arguments such as `map_t_contains_key()`, `map_t_size()`, `map_t_is_healthy()`, etc.

## bool

I would prefer using `#include <stdbool.h>` and using `bool`, `true` and `false` rather than defining your own `TRUE` and `FALSE`.  Some of your functions return a boolean value and could be changed to return a `bool` instead of an `int`.

Also, for functions that currently return `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`, I would return a `bool` with `true` indicating success and `false` indicating failure.  `EXIT_SUCCESS` is used for the return value of your program and is system dependant, so it doesn't make a very good return value for a function.

## Comparing keys

In `find_entry()`, you have this line to match a key:

> ```
> while (p_entry && p_entry->p_key != key)
> ```

The pointer comparison of `p_entry->p_key != key` seems wrong.  Two keys can be equal without having the same address (e.g. two strings).  You should call the comparator function and let a zero return value mean equal.

## Iterator function

First, this comment is wrong:

> ```
> /*******************************************************************
>  * Returns the next key in the iteration order.                    *
>  *******************************************************************/  
> void**          map_iterator_t_next         (map_iterator_t* p_iterator);
> ```

That function returns an array of two void pointers: the key and the value.

Second, there should be a warning that the values in that array will get overwritten by the next iteration.  I'm not quite sure I like this hidden array implementation.  It might be more straightforward to have two return pointers, like this:

```
bool map_iterator_next(map_iterator_t* p_iterator, void** pKey, void **pValue)
```

## Another wrong comment

> ```
> /*******************************************************************
>  * Returns the number of keys not yet iterated over.               *
>  *******************************************************************/ 
> int             map_iterator_t_has_next     (map_iterator_t* p_iterator);
> ```

This function actually returns a boolean value, not a number of keys.

## Dead code

These if statements will always be false:

```
if (!p_map->p_comparator) return NULL;
if (!p_iterator->p_map) return FALSE;
```

You could use `assert()` if you want to indicate that some condition must be true, rather than an if statement.  An assertion says "this must always be the case and if it isn't, something is wrong with my program logic".  An if statement says "this case might happen so I need to check for it".

```
assert(p_map->p_comparator != NULL);
assert(p_iterator->p_map != NULL);
```